# How do I call a function from a dictionary and get the "return"

Tags: python, function, dictionary, sum, average

Instead of the "return" result I only get this: `"function posNumAvg at 0x02B3CAE0"` when I try to print the dictionary.  Here's what code I'm referring to:

```
averages_dict = {'AvgPositive': posNumAvg, 'AvgNonPos': nonPosAvg, 'AvgAllNum': allNumAvg}
print(averages_dict)
```

print results in this:

```
{'AvgPositive': <function posNumAvg at 0x02B3CAE0>, 'AvgNonPos': <function nonPosAvg at 0x02B3CB28>, 'AvgAllNum': <function allNumAvg at 0x02B3CA98>}
```

How can I refer to the function and get the result of each function instead of what I am getting.

Comment: How do you call any other function? Don't those functions have any parameters?

Comment: Why not simply ``averages_dict['AvgPositive']()`` ?

Comment: I have to create a dictionary that stores the results of positive averages, negative average and all average.  So, the only way I can think to do that is to refer to the function within the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `find posNumAvg(input)`, your call should be to `averages_dict['AvgPositive'](input)`. Querying the dict with a key return the corresponding value, in this case the function, which you then call with your input.

Comment: The way you wrote that makes me think I may need to re-write most of my code in order to utilize your suggestion.  In this case I've no idea how else to do that.